# unable to unmount the modem

Tags: usb, usb-modem, modem, unmount

am using USB modem and i try to safely remove the modem but it gives the following message.

```
error detaching:helper exited with exit code 1:detaching device/dev/sdb USB device:/sys/devices/Pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2) 
SYNCHRONIZE CACHE FAILED: no such file or directory (continuing despite SYNCHRONIZE cache failure.) STOP UNIT: NO FILE OR SUCH DIRECTORY
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a USB modem, I assume it will create an ethernet port like eth0? If so, then I would down that port with a command like

```
sudo ifdown eth0
```

Then try to remove it after that. But if its a USB modem, and you just pull it out there really isn't any consequences unless it also acts as a storage device.

Comment: eth0 is not configured

Comment: @anandakumar enter the command `iwconfig` which will list all of the ports that are available. It might be wlan0 if its a wireless modem

Comment: fine sir.will try